# Split strings that are in a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python

I have a (66180L,) numpy.ndarray, which consists of strings in each row.

I want to go inside the rows, accessing the strings, and split them for every space in that string.

I really only want words and numbers.

How to do this?

Example:

```
sample[1,] = '[Hello] my name is Jay 12 1 2!!'
```

output:

```
['Hello', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'Jay', '12', '1', '2']
```

Comment: `np.array(' '.join(arr).split(' '))`?

Comment: Can you add an example on what you want your output to look like? I.e., are you looking to change `['my string 1','mystring2']` to `[['my','string','1'],['mystring2']]`?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you want to split the strings, there are two solutions:

1. If you want a flat list of strings:

   ```
   ar = np.array(["123 456", "12 34 56"])
   np.array(' '.join(ar).split(' '))
   ```

   ```
   ['123', '456', '12', '34', '56']
   ```
2. If you want nested lists of list:

   ```
   [x.split(" ") for x in ar]
   ```